# Find tuned vertical movement component for arduino

Tags: arduino, button

I have an automation test setup which uses pneumatics for pressing a button (ordinary push button, like the one on an Arduino uno) on the test devices. I'd like to replace the pneumatics with a smaller, if possible, electrical component, which could be controlled by an Arduino uno.

I read on the web, that people mostly use a servo motor or a solenoid in such cases. With a servo motor I'd have to somehow convert its movement to a vertical movement and the solenoid does not offer fine tuned movement, so I'd like to avoid these two.

Does somebody know of another component which might be helpful in such case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, use a servo. Easy to interface to the Uno, easy to press the button by attaching a suitable horn, no need to be precisely vertical.

Comment: Might I ask what kind of a horn would you suggest for such an use case?

Comment: The right size to fit between the servo shaft and the button.

Answer (score 1):

A solenoid should do what you want.  Your objection of *"does not offer fine tuned movement"* makes no sense.  You haven't specified what "fine tuned movement" even is, nor what about it a solenoid can't do.  You also haven't given any justification for why you need this, whatever this is.

You want to press a pushbutton.  The pushbutton will either be open or closed.  It doesn't matter whether you press it a little or a lot to close it, as long as you don't push hard enough to cause damage.  The switch will be closed either way.

A solenoid does exactly that.  The travel for activating a pushbutton is usually small, maybe around 1 mm.  The minimum force is also small, and there is a wide range between hard enough and too hard.

I really don't see how a solenoid doesn't fit your criteria, other than the made up ones with no justification.

Comment: By "fine tunning" I meant, that I'd like to be able to set the travel distance of the component and so it should not have a fixed one. The pushbutton is not directly exposed and is behind a piece of plastic. The component should exert enough force to press the button through the mentioned piece. The movable part of the selenoid is to wide to press on the piece of plastic, which is covering the device, and I suspect the servo would not produce enough force to press the button through the plastic. I will, however give it a go with the selenoid, as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: @Runo: Solenoids come in many tradeoffs of force, travel distance, and actuator width.

Comment: @RunoTheDog 'I suspect the servo would not produce enough force ...'. We all suspect all sorts of things, which on measurement may turn out to be false. 'The moveable part of the solenoid is to (sic) wide to press on the piece of plastic'. Well, duh! use a solenoid with a smaller end, or fit a thin 'presser' onto it.